# MassTransit binary serializer and MassTransit.RuntimeServices issue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, masstransit

Does anyone know if two applications can communicate to each other via MassTransit.RuntimeServices using the Binary Serializer?

As soon as I configured my bus to use the Binary Serializer, the application times-out after invoking `UseSubscriptionService()` method. When I look at the output of MassTransit.RuntimeServices process, I see an except was thrown:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Failed to deserialize message
```

Does MassTransit.RuntimeServices need to access the content of the message (and therefore, to deserialize it) in order to perform the routing?

Here are the code snippets where I configure them:

**Application 1**

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
                {
                    sbc.UseMsmq();
                    sbc.UseBinarySerializer();
                    sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
                    sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                    sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/EGQueue");
                    sbc.UseSubscriptionService("msmq://localhost/mt_subscriptions");
                });
```

**Application 2**

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.UseBinarySerializer();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/M3AgentQueue");
            sbc.Subscribe(c => c.LoadFrom(Container));
            sbc.UseSubscriptionService("msmq://localhost/mt_subscriptions");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your own version of the Runtime Services that uses the binary serializer. That's the only change you need, but the Serializer needs to match everywhere.

Comment: Thanks again @Travis, I changed the initialization method to use the binary serializer in the runtime services and everything worked fine.